# Postgres array_position(array, element) sometimes 0-indexed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, ddl

Postgres method `array_position(array, element)`, like other things in SQL, is 1-based. For example:

```
SELECT array_position(array[4,5,6], 5)    -- returns 2
```

But, I'm doing the following query to retrieve non-unique indexes from pg_catalog, along with their columns:

```sql
SELECT non_unique_indexes.indname          AS index_name,
       non_unique_indexes.relname          AS table_name,
       columns.column_name                 AS column_name,
       array_position(non_unique_indexes.indkey, columns.ordinal_position::smallint) AS column_position,
       CASE non_unique_indexes.indoption[array_position(non_unique_indexes.indkey, columns.ordinal_position::smallint)]
           WHEN 1 THEN 'DESC'
           WHEN 3 THEN 'DESC'
           ELSE 'ASC'
       END AS direction
FROM (
    SELECT pg_namespace.nspname,
           pg_class_tables.relname,
           pg_class_indexes.relname AS indname,
           pg_index.indkey,
           pg_index.indoption,
           pg_tablespace.spcname
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_index
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class pg_class_tables  ON pg_class_tables.oid  = pg_index.indrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class pg_class_indexes ON pg_class_indexes.oid = pg_index.indexrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tablespace ON pg_tablespace.oid = pg_class_indexes.reltablespace
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class_indexes.relnamespace
    WHERE pg_index.indisunique = false
      AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'my_schema'
) non_unique_indexes
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns ON columns.table_schema     = non_unique_indexes.nspname
                                     AND columns.table_name       = non_unique_indexes.relname
                                     AND columns.ordinal_position = ANY(non_unique_indexes.indkey)
ORDER BY non_unique_indexes.relname,
         non_unique_indexes.indname,
         array_position(non_unique_indexes.indkey, columns.ordinal_position::smallint)
```

The 4th select searches the `indkey` array for the column's `ordinal_position`, so for each column it gets its position in the index.

Funny thing is that first column has position 0, so I had to add `+ 1` to have it 1-based.

The subsequent `CASE` expression, where the very same value is used as index for retrieving n-th element of `indoption`, curiously works fine even though `[]` operator is 1-based as well:

```
SELECT (array[4,5,6])[2]    -- returns 5
```

How is this?

I'm currently on PG 9.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Array subscripts

You stated:

> Postgres method `array_position(array, element)`, like other things in SQL, is 1-based.

But that's subtly incorrect. Postgres arrays are 1-based ***by default***. But Postgres allows any range of integers as index. And the function [`array_position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) isn't *anything*-based. It just returns the index as found.

```
SELECT array_position('[7:9]={4,5,6}'::int[], 5);  -- returns 8!
```

See:

- [Normalize array subscripts so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1)
- [Why does PostgreSQL allow querying for array[0] even though it uses 1-based arrays?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117678/3684)

And [`pg_index.indkey`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) is **not an array** to begin with. It's type `int2vector`, which is an *internal* type, not available for general use, and **0-based**! It allows subscripts (similar to an array). A cast to `int2[]` preserves 0-based array subscripts (indices).

#### Proper query

Either way, your query doesn't seem right.

The `INNER JOIN` on `pg_tablespace` eliminates indexes stored in the default tablespace. [The manual on `pg_class.reltablespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html):

> If zero, the database's default tablespace is implied.

But there is no entry in `pg_tablespace` with `oid = 0`, so make that a `LEFT JOIN`.

There are many more caveats if you try to extract parts of the index definition by hand. What you have for `ASC` / `DESC` doesn't quite cut it. See:

- [How to get the Index column order(ASC, DESC, NULLS FIRST....) from Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121103/how-to-get-the-index-column-orderasc-desc-nulls-first-from-postgresql/18128104#18128104)

And you didn't even consider `NULLS FIRST | LAST`. Or a possible `WHERE` condition for partial indices, ...

I strongly suggest this simple, fast and reliable alternative using the built-in [System Catalog Information Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) `pg_get_indexdef()`:

```sql
SELECT ci.relname AS index_name
     , ix.indrelid::regclass::text AS table_name
     , pg_get_indexdef (ix.indexrelid) AS idx_def
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_index     ix
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     ci ON ci.oid = ix.indexrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = ci.relnamespace
WHERE  ix.indisunique = false
AND    ns.nspname = 'my_schema'
ORDER  BY 2, 1;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)

> Reconstructs the creating command for an index. (This is a decompiled reconstruction, not the original text of the command.)

This gets all aspects right and keeps working across Postgres versions.

#### Your query

If you insist on decomposing the index definition, this query should basically work (as of Postgres 14):

```sql
SELECT ci.relname AS index_name
     , ct.relname AS table_name
     , pg_get_indexdef (ix.indexrelid, pos::int, false) AS idx_expression
     , CASE WHEN ia.indopt & 1 = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END AS direction
     , CASE WHEN ia.indopt & 2 = 2 THEN 'NULLS FIRST' ELSE 'NULLS LAST' END AS direction_nulls
     , pg_get_expr(ix.indpred, ix.indrelid) AS where_clause
     , ia.pos AS column_position
     , ix.indkey
     , ix.indoption
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_index     ix
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     ct ON ct.oid = ix.indrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     ci ON ci.oid = ix.indexrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = ci.relnamespace
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tablespace ts ON ts.oid = ci.reltablespace
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL unnest(ix.indkey, ix.indoption) WITH ORDINALITY AS ia(attnum, indopt, pos)
WHERE  ix.indisunique = false
AND    ns.nspname = 'my_schema'
ORDER  BY ct.relname, ci.relname, ia.pos;
```

But the "proper query" is far more stable and reliable.

In particular I use `unnest()` with multiple arguments to unnest `indkey` and `indoption` in lockstep and with ordinal (1-based) position. See:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

I use [`pg_get_indexdef()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to reconstruct each index field. This also covers expressions, not just plain table columns.

I added `direction_nulls` indicating `NULLS FIRST | LAST`, see:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

And `where_clause` with a decompiled `WHERE` clause for partial indices (using [`pg_get_expr()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)).

Comment: Wow! So much things ;-) Ok, first, thanks for the explanation of the array thing. On the query: we only have tables, indexes etc in our tablespaces, not no problem here. Also, I used the `pg_get_indexdef` method to get a quick list of all creation commands, replace a word in them, and recreate. But, in this context, I just need to retrieve some properties of the index to store them in a SQLite file, for later use. Also, we always use btree indexes, so, yes, values of `indoption` in (1,3) means DESC, values in (0,2) means ASC (we don't consider `NULL LAST | FIRST` here, neither `where_clause`s)

Comment: By the way, thanks for the long explanation and for pointing out potential problems of my query. I will use as a prompt to improve my query. I will have to study some constructs before, eheh, like `LATERAL` and `WITH ORDINALITY` ;-)

Comment: Note that I got mislead by the fact that `array_position(pg_constraint.conkey, columns.ordinal_position::smallint)` returns a 1-based result. As you pointed out, `indkey` is `int2vector`, while `conkey` is `int2[]`. Seems strange they used two different datatypes for similar data, but they probably have a good reason for that I suppose.

Comment: @Teejay: I added a link for `WITH ORDINALITY`.