# How can I drop all indexes of a table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, metadata, dynamic-sql, ddl

I keep having this problem: I have like 20 indexes on a table that I need to drop in order to do testing. Dropping the table doesn't drop all of this metadata.

There doesn't seem to be a wildcard `drop index ix_table_*` or any useful command. There seem to be some bash loops around psql you can write.
There must be something better! Thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6777904/3961156

Comment: When you say "all indexes", do you mean to include constraints (`UNIQUE`, `PK`, `EXCLUDE`) that are implemented by creating an index implicitly?

Comment: Nope, just the indexes in this case.

Answer (score 25):

Assuming you only want to drop plain indexes:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN   
   SELECT 'DROP INDEX ' || string_agg(indexrelid::regclass::text, ', ')
   FROM   pg_index  i
   LEFT   JOIN pg_depend d ON d.objid = i.indexrelid
                          AND d.deptype = 'i'
   WHERE  i.indrelid = 'table_name'::regclass  -- possibly schema-qualified
   AND    d.objid IS NULL                      -- no internal dependency
   INTO   _sql;
   
   IF _sql IS NOT NULL THEN                    -- only if index(es) found
     EXECUTE _sql;
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

Does not touch indexes created as implementation detail of constraints (`UNIQUE`, `PK`, `EXCLUDE`).
[The documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html)

> ```
> DEPENDENCY_INTERNAL (i)
> ```
>
> The dependent object was created as part of creation of the referenced
> object, and is really just a part of its internal implementation.

You could wrap this in a function for repeated execution.
Related:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Related:

- [DROP FUNCTION without knowing the number/type of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622908/drop-function-without-knowing-the-number-type-of-parameters/7623246#7623246)

---

Aside: This is a misunderstanding:

> Dropping the table doesn't drop all of this metadata.

Dropping a table **always** cascades to all indexes on the table.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why dropping the table would not cascade to the indexes? Because it doesn't. The tables & indexes were generated by me playing around with sql alchemy declarative base and mixin classes -- something that is a bit of a black box to me still.

Comment: @Erin: Are you sure, there isn't a second table of the same name in a different schema?

Comment: Took a while to understand that the input to this query is `'tbl'`

Comment: @BenjaminCrouzier: I changed to `'your_table_name_here'` to make it clearer.

Comment: In order to clean indexes only from user's tables, use this condition: `where not indrelid::regclass::varchar like 'pg_%'`

Comment: @Andremoniy: While providing a user's table name, that's not necessary. Maybe as safety measure for a general-purpose function. But `DROP INDEX` is only allowed for the owner of the table (or superusers) anyway.

Comment: Be careful, this SQL fails if there is no index on the named table.

Comment: @Neil: Consider the update: not any more.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I remove all indexes from postgres, excluding all pkey.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_all_indexes() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  i RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 
    (SELECT relname FROM pg_class
       -- exclude all pkey, exclude system catalog which starts with 'pg_'
      WHERE relkind = 'i' AND relname NOT LIKE '%_pkey%' AND relname NOT LIKE 'pg_%')
  LOOP
    -- RAISE INFO 'DROPING INDEX: %', i.relname;
    EXECUTE 'DROP INDEX ' || i.relname;
  END LOOP;
RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To execute:

```
SELECT drop_all_indexes();
```

Before actually executing 'DROP INDEX xxx', I would comment out the line 'EXECUTE ...' using '-- ', and uncomment the 'RAISE INFO' line, run it with 'select func_name();' and double check I'm not dropping something I should not.

For our application, we have all schema statements including indexes creation in one file **app.sql**. Before this whole project goes to production, we want to clean up all historically created indexes, then recreate them using:

```
psql -f /path/to/app.sql
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot! What I need to do is just change the select query a bit to fulfill my requirement. The idea of RAISE INFO saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 7):

The query below drops all **user** indexes which are **not** related with any **constraint** (primary key, unique key)

```
SELECT
    format('DROP INDEX %I.%I;', n.nspname, c_ind.relname)
  FROM pg_index ind
  JOIN pg_class c_ind ON c_ind.oid = ind.indexrelid
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c_ind.relnamespace
  LEFT JOIN pg_constraint cons ON cons.conindid = ind.indexrelid
  WHERE
    n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog','information_schema') AND 
    n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'::TEXT AND
    cons.oid IS NULL
```

You can use `\gexec` meta-command feature of psql to execute statement

Comment: ps. Here's something similar for dropping constraints, should it help: `SELECT format ('ALTER TABLE %I.%I DROP CONSTRAINT %I;', nsp.nspname, rel.relname, con.conname)  
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname     = 'cam'
       order by  con.conname -- hacky way to ensure FKs come before PKs`

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of the KISS, I would consider the approach mentioned in the official implementation
[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/sql-altertable.html#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20to%20drop%20all%20constraints%20on%20a%20table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/sql-altertable.html#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20to%20drop%20all%20constraints%20on%20a%20table)

```sql
-- store table structure 
-- into temp table 
create temporary table t$ as 
select * from table_name limit 0;
-- drop the table, 
-- 'cascade' ensures it will not 
-- complain about any dependencies
drop table table_name cascade;
-- recreate the original table
create table table_name as 
select * from t$;
-- drop temporary table
drop table t$;
```