# How to SELECT data from a postgreSQL INDEX?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

If I created an index with following command: `CREATE INDEX ixname ON tbname (id);`

Where `ixname` is the name of index, `tbname` is the table name for which the index is being created and `id` is the column the index is for.

Now, if I wanted to view what's in `ixname`, how would I do it? (I'm asking with the assumption that an index is a relation/table with sorted column)

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, and the referenced question/answer do not help.

Comment: The referenced answer doesn't really do what you seem to think it does. If you want to know what an index includes, look at its definition and write a query that gets just that from the relevant table if you care to do so.

Comment: I've edited to hopefully clarify the question.

Comment: The answer is simple: you don't. You select from the table. If it makes sense, Postgres will retrieve the data from the index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I know I'm not suppose to fetch anything from index, I understand what indexes are for. But as learning exercise and to ensure everything in database is properly set, I wanted to view what's in the index relation.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how you would retrieve the data that is stored in column `id` within table `tbname`, or are you trying to ask how you would subsequently be able to determine the definition of index `ixname` ?

Comment: @MarkBannister I want to view the sorted data stored in index, not from the table or column it was created on.

Comment: Robert Holland - see a_horse_with_no_name's comment.

Comment: Again, that's not doing what you seem to think it is. But if you are looking for that, your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309786/how-do-i-force-postgres-to-use-a-particular-index

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just can't. Not as a client, not using SQL.

Data in the index is internal to PostgreSQL, and it's not accessible to the outside world. You can [introspect your index *definitions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777456/list-all-index-names-column-names-and-its-table-name-of-a-postgresql-database) (using `pg_indexes` table or `pg_get_indexdef` function), but you can't look up what's actually stored in those.

Well, you technically can [find the file(s)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html) in which the index data is stored (use `pg_class.relfilenode` and checking for files in `base/` subdirectory), and decode the [binary data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html) of their b-trees (or whatever your indexes use), but I'm not sure this is what you want to do. Unless you intend to learn or hack PostgreSQL internals.

Comment: Thank you, this is much more helpful than commenters.

Comment: If anybody found any quick solution on how to view the content of index, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can with [*pg_filedump*](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pg_filedump.git) utility

#### step 1. Installing *pg_filedump* in Debian

```sh
$ git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/pg_filedump.git
$ cd pg_filedump/
$ make
$ make install

# note the line /usr/bin/install -c  pg_filedump '/usr/lib/postgresql/17/bin'

# add env var
$ PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/17/bin

# check that it works
$ pg_filedump -h
```

#### step 2. Finding path to the index file via SQL

```sql
SHOW data_directory;
-- /var/lib/postgresql/17/main

-- list your indices
SELECT *
FROM pg_indexes;

-- locate particular index
SELECT pg_relation_filepath('name_of_target_index');
-- let's say output is
-- base/123/4567
```

#### step 3. Look inside the index file

```sh
$ cd /var/lib/postgresql/17/main/base/123/
$ pg_filedump -D int,varchar 4567
```

Play with *pg_filedump* parameters to get nice visualization. Inspired by https://blog.dbi-services.com/displaying-the-contents-of-a-postgresql-data-file-with-pg_filedump/