# How to acess Postgresql's GIN "posting list"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

"A GIN index stores a set of (key, posting list) pairs, where a posting list is a set of row IDs in which the key occurs. "
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-intro.html

How can I access this list of (key,posting list)?

Comment: Why do you think you need that? What problem are you trying to solve with that information?

Comment: The [pageinspect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html#id-1.11.7.32.8)  module is probably your best chance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I literally need this kind of info. a mapping from bag of words to rows that contain them

Comment: @YoraiLevi If you want to access `(key,posting list)` meaning you access all the distinct base lexemes. That is a lot. If you just want to query certain lexemes being contained in which row, you can just use GIN index tsvector_ops.

Comment: @Mark I need everything

Comment: @YoraiLevi I've made a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=051815cf24494f2fbb59fbc6b5f77933). Let me know if  that is what you want.

Comment: Simply perform the corresponding SQL query, and you get your result.

Comment: Thanks @Mark that's almost it. I don't want the lexemes for each single line(yet) I need them aggregated. It's simple to do from the query demo you gave but it's going to compute it again where I hoped to reuse the index for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822114/how-to-select-data-from-a-postgresql-index hopefully by 2030 it will be easier